# How to re-enable html5 audio volume controls in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio

About a week ago Chrome suddenly changed the way it displays html5 audio (and video) volume controls: now I can only mute/unmute, but there is no volume slider anymore. Can I somehow change it back?

Comment: Apart from doing your own controls, or unsetting chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls I didn't find any way... According to [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/QHsKCfRJiT8), it might worse a FR so they bring it back. And there actually are already a few bug reports: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=848905 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=836432

Comment: This is a duplicate question that has already been answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1329790/chrome-67-missing-volume-slider