# Did HTML Audio do some update?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

So yesterday I closed my project and today when I opened it the HTML Audio players layout has changed and the volume control has dissapearead. It was a plain player with no design. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: HTML5 Audio & Video Controls has been updated. I saw it recently

Comment: ... How many of these unanswerable questions will we get? Yes Chrome did update their layout in v67. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735930/how-to-re-enable-html5-audio-volume-controls-in-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, Chrome 67 redesigned the media player and for some reason left out audio controls, a workaround is to change your chrome flag to use the old player.

> chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls

There has already been a fair few bug reports and Feature requests to bring this feature back i.e.

> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/QHsKCfRJiT8